# Can word movement in vim skip the symbols?

Tags: vim

For example, what I want:

```
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html
 ------>------>----------->
 w       w         w
```

what Vim behaves:

```
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html
 --->-->----->>---------->>
 w   w   w   w    w      w
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
nnoremap w /\v(^\|\A)\zs\a<cr>
onoremap w /\v(^\|\A)\zs\a<cr>
xnoremap w /\v(^\|\A)\zs\a<cr>
```

It maps the 'w' key to a search. This search looks for any alphabetic character that is preceded by either a non-alphabetic character, or a start of line. The various different mapping modes (`nnoremap`, `onoremap`, `xnoremap`) are so that it works in visual mode and as an argument to an operator, e.g. `dw` will delete our custom word rather than the default meaning of a word.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mapping `w` to this command because the default behavior is often useful, I'd remap another key to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Just set [`'iskeyword'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27) to the desired value.